# Как сохранить ревизию вопроса при редактировании в первые 5 минут?

Tags: поддержка

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/490665/revisions

```
#3   2016-02-09 15:11:18Z  
#2   2016-02-09 15:08:26Z  
#1   2016-02-09 15:07:43Z
```

Как такого добиться?

Comment: Если кто-то добавляет комментарий или (кажется) другой ответ в течение grace period, то он при этом автоматически заканчивается.

Comment: @VladD Не для других ответов. Добавленный ответ заканчивает срок только для вопроса.

Comment: @LiveForever: Правда? Не знал, спасибо.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Новая версия при редактировании в течение 5 минут](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2301)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо. Не смог его найти, когда спрашивал.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Причина сохранения в этом:

> Асимптотика квадратичная получается... – Qwertiy 14 минут назад

Временной интервал, когда все правки сливаются в одну, заканчивается раньше положенных 5 минут, если был добавлен комментарий (или ответ к вопросу). [Источник](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876).

---

Скриншот из истории вопроса в качестве иллюстрации:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если я сам коммент добавлю, то не сработает? Эх, жаль.. Не выйдет намеренно использовать.

Comment: Верно: комментарий должен быть не от редактора.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а где ты такую историю смотришь? Что-то модераторское?

Comment: @Qwertiy [Здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/490665/timeline) - история доступна всем, но нужно знать адрес (заменить revisions на  timeline вручную).

Comment: @Qwertiy я думал, что модераторское, оказывается, что нет. :)